# How to convert "std::vector<std::string>" to "const char* array"?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

There is a function that needs a const char* array, basically a list of words. Because this list of word can change, I can not declare and initalize this array at program start. For now, I have a vector of strings and I need to convert this to an array of const char*. How can this be done? Thanks!

Example:

```
std::vector<std::string> list;
list.push_back("word1");
list.push_back("word2"); // and so on...

const char* wordList[] = ???
```

Comment: I dont see how the other answer can solve my problem. Maybe someone can give a short example?

Comment: The other answer shows a perfect example on how to construct a `char const**` is there anything else your question needs that isn't answered in the other answer?

Comment: You only need `const char ** wordList`, even if the functions parameter is declared `const char* wordList[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't **convert** it, but it's straightforward to **create** an array:

```
std::vector<const char*> strings;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
    strings.push_back(list[i].c_str();
```

And now, `strings.data()` gives you an array of `const char*`.

Note that `strings` should not be used after `list` has been destroyed, since it holds pointers to data that lives in `list`. I'd probably wrap this in a function:

```
void call_C_function(const std::vector<std::string>& list) {
    std::vector<const char*> strings;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        strings.push_back(list[i].c_str());
    c_function(strings.data());
}
```

That way, `strings` will live only through the call to `c_function`, and there is no danger of it outlasting `list`.

Comment: Should probably `reserve` the memory as well.

Comment: @hegel5000 vs @pete-becker : `data()` vs `c_str()` real difference?

Comment: @NathanOliver -- there are lots of variations. I chose this as the most straightforward way to show how to approach the problem. My goal was to show the general form of the solution, and, in particular, to clarify that this is a **new object** and not a conversion.

Comment: @Sandburg They do the same thing since c++11. Edit : Though since c++17 there is a non-const `data()`.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

No matter what, you'll hit some complicated lifetime issues, but I think this is the simplest way:

```
std::vector<const char*> ptrs;
for (std::string const& str : list) {
  ptrs.push_back(str.data());
}
```

If you need your `const char**`, you can call `ptrs.data()`.  The issue, of course, is that `ptrs` and `list` must both stay alive for `ptrs.data()` to be valid.

Another thing to watch out for is that if you `push_back` more elements to `list`, then `list` could reallocate, which would invalidate the pointers in `ptrs`.